# Chrome extension opens multiple tabs

Tags: chrome-web-store

I built an extension for chrome, I would like to open new tab when the user click on the extension icon.

This is the code for that:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab){
let newURL = "chrome://newtab";
chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });});
```

When I click the extension icon it multiple the number of new tabs(1 -> 2 -> 4...).

If I change the new URL to "google.com" its work fine, only open one tab when clicked.

Any ideas how to solve this bug?